# Blocks storage compatibility among different Ethereum Clients

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-interoperation

Does anyone know if there are differences among the file generated to store the blocks by different Ethereum clients?
I imagined that this answer is different depending on the consensus algorithm, right?
So, are the files the same on Ethereum mainnet? May I take files generated by Geth and use them in a Besu client?
If we use Ethereum clients to create permissioned networks, are the files compatible?

Answer (score 1):

> I imagined that this answer is different depending on the consensus algorithm, right?

It's more likely to be related to the client implementation. Consensus is more about agreeing on the contents of a block, rather than how the block's data is stored.

Different clients have chosen different databases in which to store the block/state data.

- Geth (Go) uses Google's [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb)
- Parity/OpenEthereum (Rust) uses RocksDB (I think with BloomDB as an intermediate layer?)
- Besu (Java) also uses [RocksDB](https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/blob/e230a445bb457bbac27bf4c384da449ccbd3f043/plugins/rocksdb/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/besu/plugin/services/storage/rocksdb/RocksDBKeyValuePrivacyStorageFactory.java#L23)

> May I take files generated by Geth and use them in a Besu client?

You'll need to convert between database file formats. I'm not sure how practicable this would be, or even if they *are* compatible, even after conversion. (Someone closer to client development might be able to give a more detailed answer.)